# How to get taggable_friends list with FQL?

Tags: php, facebook-fql

I want to know how to get **taggable_friends** list with FQL in facebook **v2.0**. How can i get all facebook friend list using FQL? Thanks.

Comment: why FQL and not Graph API?

Comment: facebook api has changed a lot ??..:p

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, in addition, FQL is being phased out after v2.0.